# Пару вопросов про react native

Tags: reactjs, mobile-development, react-native, мобильная-разработка

Есть проект на обычном `rеact+redux+router`. Стал смотреть в  сторну `react-native`. Возник вопрос есть ли смысл переписывать проект на него? Как понимаю в `react-native` создается apk приложение для смартфона, которое может быть запущено как под `ios`, так и под `android`. Но в тоже время можно ведь имея веб-версию проекта на обычном реакте зайти на него с помощью любого смартфона используя браузер. Исходя из этого я не совсем понял преимуществ `react-native` перед обычным react. ПОдскажите пожалуйста, есть ли смысл переносить проект на react-native, если да, то какие преимущества это даст?

Comment: в вашей ситуации смысла переносить нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы получаете возможности native приложения, такие как:

- работа в офлайне
- использование api мобильной платформы, доступ к железу: камеры, сенсоры, оплаты,
- возможность оптимизации интерфейса и скорости работы приложения
- листинг в магазинах Appstore, Google Play